A skew Varignon problem
The midpoints of segments in the polyline WTPJINOQ are vertices of quadrilateral AEBH. AE=13, EB=9, BH=15, HA=19, EH=18, AB=20. The red lines have the same length. What is the length of the red lines?

Curiously, no matter where you start with point W, the red lines all have the same length if you follow the midpoint ordering HBEAHBE. I'm wondering if this variation on Varignon's problem is known, and if the length of the red lines can be calculated from the side lengths and diagonals.

All red lines are of the same length because $IWNT$, $NTOP$ and $OPQJ$ are parallelograms by construction. Note also that:
$$
\vec{IW}=\vec{IP}+\vec{PW}=2(\vec{AE}+\vec{BH})
$$
We have then, by the cosine rule:
$$
IW^2=4(AE^2+BH^2-2AE\cdot BH\cos\alpha),
$$
where the angle $\alpha$ between $AE$ and $BH$ is equal to
$\epsilon+\beta-\pi$,
having set $\epsilon=\angle AEB$ and $\beta=\angle EBH$.
To compute $\alpha$ we can then find $\epsilon$ and $\beta$ with the cosine rule:
$$
\cos\epsilon={AE^2+BE^2-AB^2\over 2 AE\cdot BE}=-{25\over39},
\quad
\sin\epsilon=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\epsilon}={8\sqrt{14}\over39},
$$
$$
\cos\beta={EB^2+BH^2-EH^2\over 2 EB\cdot BH}=-{1\over15},
\quad
\sin\beta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\beta}={4\sqrt{14}\over15},
$$
and use the addition rule:
$$
\cos\alpha=-\cos(\epsilon+\beta)=
-\cos\epsilon\cos\beta+\sin\epsilon\sin\beta={47\over65}.
$$
Finally:
$$
IW=2\sqrt{AE^2+BH^2-2AE\cdot BH\cos\alpha}=8\sqrt7.
$$


An easier method:  find the midpoints of the diagonals and construct a segment 4 times longer. The red lines are parallel and have the same length.

Take any red line like $WI$. It is the result of $4$ half-turns about $H,B,E,A$. The result of any two half-turns about successive points $O_1,O_2$ is a translation in the distance $2O_1O_2$. So the red line $WI$ is the vector sum of $2HB+2EA$. $EAHB$ half-turns yield the exact same translation for $PO$, so $PO=WI$. Similar logic shows $BEAH$ and $AHBE$ cause $TN=JQ$.
Now, we still need to show that both pairs of red vectors are equal. I.e., we need to prove $HB+EA=AH+BE$. But consider translating $EA$ so that $E$ lies on $B$, and translating $EB$ so that $E$ lies on $B$. The parallelograms formed are the same, and its lower left vertex, call it $X$ forms the segment $XH$, which is half the vector sum that represents the translations. So all red lines represent the same vector.
Edit:  from this it should be clear that the position of $W$ and any points it generates is immaterial to generating the red lines (other than where they appear), and that the only controlling variables here are the positions of the quadrilateral vertices, which could be calculated via coordinate approaches (or trig, as in Intelligenti pauca's answer).
